# Xamarin essentials dosent have all the permisions I need

Tags: xamarin

I have a xamarin forms app, that needs to ask some specific permission that are not in the Xamarin essentials documentation, for example Bluetooth.

In IOS I did a Class that handles this

```
  public class BluetoothService : IBluetoothService
    {
        public Task<PermissionStatus> CheckPermissionAsync()
        {
            switch (CBManager.Authorization)
            {
                case CBManagerAuthorization.AllowedAlways:
                    return Task.FromResult(PermissionStatus.Granted);
                case CBManagerAuthorization.Restricted:
                    return Task.FromResult(PermissionStatus.Restricted);
                case CBManagerAuthorization.NotDetermined:
                    return Task.FromResult(PermissionStatus.Unknown);
                default:
                    return Task.FromResult(PermissionStatus.Denied);
            }
        }

        public async Task<PermissionStatus> RequestPermissionAsync()
        {
            // Initializing CBCentralManager will present the Bluetooth permission dialog.
            new CBCentralManager();
            PermissionStatus status;
            do
            {
                status = await CheckPermissionAsync();
                await Task.Delay(200);
            } while (status == PermissionStatus.Unknown);
            return status;
        }
    }
```

how can I do this as well for android and check the status in a button

Comment: What is the question? You are just writing a bunch of statements here. What do you specifically need help with? You've correctly concluded that Xamarin.Essentials doesn't have support for asking for the bluetooth permission on iOS 13 and up. However, which library are you using for your bluetooth comms? If you are writing it yourself, what prevents you from asking for the permission yourself?

Comment: I am very surprised that you did not give me negative points lol, but you are right   is a bunch of nonsense, what I need is to ask permission for Network Access, Bluetooth, and geolocation. I edited m question

Comment: The docs show an example of how to write a custom [read/write permission.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#extending-permissions) Should be fairly trivial to modify the example to bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you. I did A dependency service for IOS, could you help me to implement it on Android, and call in in a button, I will edit my question

Comment: Have you checked document [Extending Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#extending-permissions) and tried it?